# Z270X Ultra Gaming which dimm slots?

Tags: dual-channel

Picture:

[image]

So I don't know which slots to put my ram sticks? (2x8gb)
Please help.

BTW the picture is on a other motherboard bit the layout is the same!

Comment: What does the manual say?

Answer (score 0):

The Fine Manual says to use slots DDR4_4 and DDR4_2 OR DDR4_2 and DDR4_1 - the motherboard should automatically pick up what sort of ram and handle the necessary bit.

You can find this in [TFM](http://download.gigabyte.asia/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-z270x-gaming5_e.pdf) on page 11

[image]